# Problems starting a JBoss 7.02 server on computer startup

Tags: java, windows-server-2008, batch-file, jboss

I have a JBoss 7.02 server running on a Windows Server 2008 machine. The server needs to be kept running at all times, but every so often the host machine will restart leaving the application inaccessible until I manually log back into the machine and run it again.

I need a way to start the server as soon as the computer starts, without the need for any user action. I have a bat file that cleans the deployments folder and then runs the standalone.bat. We routinely use this bat file to run the server without issue. So I set up a task in the Task Scheduler to run a shortcut pointing to this bat file. The task is set to run "When the computer starts". Restarting the host machine resulted in Windows failing to boot and missing system files.

Here is the makeup of the bat file, which is stored in the jboss server folder:

```
set jboss=%CD%
cd /d %jboss%\standalone\tmp
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)
cd %jboss%\standalone\deployments
del *.deployed
del *.failed
del *.isdeploying
del *.undeployed
call %jboss%\bin\standalone.bat
```

My questions are...
1) What caused this to fail?
2) Is there a better or more reliable way to run a JBoss server on system startup?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution to my problem. A JBoss server can be configured as a service and set to start automatically. Here are the steps to do so:

---

1. On the www.jboss.org/jbossweb/downloads web site, search for the
   current packages of the "Jboss Web Native Connectors", and download
   the binaries appropriate for the Windows operating system you are
   using. For example, if the current package is at release 2.0.10,
   then download the zip file for binaries 2.0.10-windows x64.
2. Unzip the downloaded archive file to the JBoss root directory. For
   example: C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final. If prompted to do so, overwrite any existing files with the same names.
3. Use your text editor to open the service.bat file under the
   \bin directory. Save a copy of the file as service.old
   so you have a backup.
4. Set the SVCNAME, SVCDISP and SVCDESC properties to something
   meaningful. For example:

   - set SVCNAME=JBoss7server
   - set SVCDISP=JBoss Server for CSP release X
   - set SVCDESC=JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final - Windows x64 - CSP release X
5. Comment out the JAVA_OPTS property by adding REM to the beginning of
   the line. For example:

   - REM set JAVA_OPTS=-X
6. Replace all occurrences of run.bat with standalone.bat.
7. Replace all occurrences of run.log with standalone.log.
8. Replace all occurrences of the command

   - call shutdown -S < .s.lock >>
     shutdown.log 2>&1
   - with this command
   - call jboss-cli.bat --connect
     --command=:shutdown >> shutdown.log 2>&1
9. Save the modified service.bat file.
10. Launch the Windows command line and execute the following command to install and register the "JBoss Server for CSP release X" service:

    - service.bat install
11. Open Server Manager > Configuration > Services and verify that the "JBoss Server for CSP release X" service was registered.
12. (Optional) Change the Startup Type for this service to Automatic.
13. Start the "JBoss Service for CSP release X" service.
14. Check the log file \bin\standalone.log to verify that the JBoss server started up successfully.